# Why isn't AES ENCRYPT and DECRYPT working in xampp mysql?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have an sql command like so : `INSERT INTO data(pass) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('123456',UNHEX(SHA2('my phrase',512))))` and whenever I run it, my sql server turns off and I get the following error : mysql is gone away.
Besides I'm not getting any error with other commands.
This is my log :

```
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:43:34 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

And here is my mysql log :

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=323988
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 323997; transaction id 328
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-26 19:29:04 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Any solution ? thanks in advance

Comment: The message tells you to press the "Logs" button to the view error logs. Please do that (and then add them to your question).

Comment: @Solarflare I updated my question